# Relationship between roots of $P(x)$ and $P(x+q)$

Tags: polynomials

> Is there any special relationship between the roots of $P(x)$ and $P(x+q) \, \,\text{where}\,q\in\mathbb{Z}$?
>   $P(x)$ is an arbitrary polynomial with an arbitrary degree.

I've notice something. When $P(x+q)$ is divided by $(x+q)$, the remainder is always $$r(x)=r_1r_2r_3\cdots r_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}r_i\,\text{where $r_i$ are the roots of $P(x)$}$$
 Is this just arbitrary?

Comment: $\;r\in\Bbb C\;$ is a root of $\;P(x)\iff r-q\;$ is a root pf $\;P(x+q)\;$ ...pretty boring, indeed.

Comment: Not sure what the $\forall q\in\mathbb{Z}$ is supposed to mean but by replacing $x$ by $x+q$ you're just shifting the entire thing by $-q$.

Comment: If $P(x)=\prod_i(x-r_i)$, then $P(x+q)=\prod_i(x+q-r_i)=\prod_i(x-(r_i-q))$. Therefore, the roots of $P(x+q)$ are the roots of $P$ subtracted by $q$. It is not a boring property, it was used by all the people that discovered formulas in radicals to solve the general polynomial of the few degrees for which such formula exists.

Comment: The second property you mentioned is due to the following: The remainder after division by $x+q$ is equal to the value of the polynomial that you are dividing at $x=-q$. If the polynomial being divided is $P(x+q)$, then the remainder if $P(-q+q)=P(0)$. It is part of Vietta's formulas that $P(0)$ is equal to the product of the roots **times** $(-1)^{deg(P)}$.